# Complex XML to deserialize into C# Classes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, deserialization

How can I deserialize the xml below into c# classes

```
<Transaction ControlNumber="0001">
    <ST>
        <ST01>271</ST01>
    </ST>
    <BHT>
        <BHT01>022</BHT01>
    </BHT>
    <HierarchicalLoop LoopId="2000A" LoopName="Information Source Level" Id="1" ParentId=""></HierarchicalLoop>
    <HierarchicalLoop LoopId="2000A" LoopName="Information Source Level" Id="2" ParentId=""></HierarchicalLoop>
    <HierarchicalLoop LoopId="2000A" LoopName="Information Source Level" Id="3" ParentId=""></HierarchicalLoop>
</Transaction>
```

I know it would be easy if the `HierarchicalLoop` node is wrapped in a `HierarchicalLoops` node, but I have no choice since it is not allowed to change the XML format. I'm seeking for guidance on the `HierarchicalLoop` node contained in `Transaction`, where in `Transaction` has other different child nodes too! I'm also using `XmlSerializer` class from C# to parse the XML. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Put xml as text not as image. 2. This xml is not well formed: tags are not closed. Publish well formed xml!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, my bad. I already edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I already got this, this is now resolved. It was a bit of a silly question I guess.

```
public class Transaction
{
    [XmlAttribute("ControlNumber")]
    public string ControlNumber { get; set; }

    public ST ST { get; set; }

    public BHT BHT { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("HierarchicalLoop")]
    public List<HierarchicalLoop> HierarchicalLoops { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create set of classes:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public ST ST { get; set; }
    public BHT BHT { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public List<HierarchicalLoop> HierarchicalLoop { get; set; } // maybe HierarchicalLoop[]
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ControlNumber { get; set; } // maybe int
}
public class ST
{
    public string ST01 { get; set; } // maybe int
}

public class BHT
{
    public string BHT01 { get; set; } // maybe int
}

public class HierarchicalLoop
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LoopId { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string LoopName { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Id { get; set; } // maybe int
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Transaction transaction;
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transaction));

using (var fs = new FileStream("in.xml", FileMode.Open))
    transaction = (Transaction)xs.Deserialize(fs);

using (var fs = new FileStream("out.xml", FileMode.Create))
    xs.Serialize(fs, transaction);
```